# Can a person listen to the recorded songs of bhakti ? Importance of music in bhakti?

Tags: bhakti

Can a person listen to the recorded songs of bhakti towards god i.e. bhakti songs ? Or Is it waste of time ?

Should a person only chant the name of god by himself ?

What is the importance of music in devotion towards god ?